# Group isomorphism $R^{\times} \simeq C_n\times C_2$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-groups

Let $n$ be an positive integer and $R:=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2,nX)$.

Do we have $R^{\times} \simeq C_n\times C_2$ (the group of units of $R$) as it seems to be the case for small values of $n$.

If so, do you have a proof?

NEW EDITS to fulfill ""This question does not appear to be about research level mathematics within the scope defined in the help center." – Mark Sapir, Steven Landsburg, Frieder Ladisch"

Thanks Laurent.
Could we find a finite ring $R$, such that $R^{\times} \simeq C_n\times C_2$? I'm interesting in particular in $n=17$ and $n=19$ but $n=47$ would be useful too.

Comment: Your new question looks more suitable for MathSE, and you should provide a little more context: what have you tried?

Comment: I first looked at $2n$ to be non-totient numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontotient . The first ones being $14$ and $26$, but with $R = \mathbb{F}_{2^3} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $R=\mathbb{F}_{3^3}$ I found a "satisfying" finite ring.

Comment: So, you solved your own question for $n=17$. What about $n=19$ and $n=47$? Hint: a finite commutative ring $R$ splits as direct product $R_1\dots R_k$ with each $R_i$ local with maximal ideal $M_i$, and $p_i$ being the characteristic of $R_i/M_i$, the order of $R_i^\times$ is $|R_i/M_i-1|.|M_i|$, where $|M_i|$ is some power of $p_i$.

Comment: Your hint is useful, but how did I solve my own question for $n=17$?

Comment: Oops sorry I misread. Actually from my hint you have enough information to discard all these three (17,19,47) numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Every element $f$ of $R$ is the class of some $a+bX$ ($a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$). One sees immediately that $a$ is unique and $b$ is unique modulo $n$ (thus, as an additive group, $R\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$). Moreover, $f$ is a unit if and only if $a=\pm1$. To conclude, we have an isomorphism
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\left\{\pm1\right\}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{\sim} & R^\times \\
(\varepsilon, b\bmod n) & \longmapsto & \text{class of }\:\varepsilon\,(1+bX).
\end{array}
$$